# Validar un CheckBox en un JTable - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

He colocado un `checkbox` en un *JTable*. El problema es que cuando marco y hago click en el botón prueba (`btnPrueba`), me aparece un mensaje de validación `"marque"`. ¿Cómo haría para valide correctamente?:

```
protected void btnPruebaActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tbDocNoUbicado.getRowCount(); i++){
        Boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf((boolean) tbDocNoUbicado.getValueAt(i, 13));
        String col = (String) tbDocNoUbicado.getValueAt(i, 0);

        if(checked == true){
            System.out.println(col);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "marque");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendiendo en cuenta que la columna *13* es la correcta y que contiene el *checkbox* , podría optar por realizar un *cast* diferente del valor de la columna , accediendo al método *toString()*

```
Boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(tbDocNoUbicado.getValueAt(i,13).toString());
if(checked){ ...}
else {....}
```

Una forma de validar es utilizar una variable auxiliar para contar la cantidad de valores *check* marcados

```
   int cont =0;  /* Var Auxiliar*/
   Boolean checked = false;
   for(int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++){
        checked = Boolean.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
        /* Si está marcado , aumentamos el valor*/
        if(checked){
          cont++;
          break;
        } 
   }
   if(cont==0){ /* si es 0 , es porque no hay opciones marcadas*/
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "marque");
   }
```

Comment: ya lo cambié el cast pero me sigue saliendo el mensaje de validación. hago click en el boton sin marcar ningun `checkbox` y aparece el mensaje eso esta bien, pero cuando marco un `checkbox` o mas me sale el mensaje de validacion.

Comment: Es que la única forma que no le muestre el mensaje _"marque"_  **es que todos los check estén marcados** , ya qué con el _for_ hace la validación para cada fila .

Comment: solo quiero que aparezca el mensaje cuando no este ningun checkbox marcado, si uno este marcado ya no aparezca el mensaje

Comment: @Angelica agregué una opción para validar esto.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda